# Using current value of global variable in function definition

Tags: r

I have a global variable `x` and want to build a function `f` that returns the value of `x` at the time the function is created. Example:

```
x <- 5
f <- function() return(x)
f()
> 5
x <- 10
f()
> 10 # Should return 5
```

I want a function that always return `5` (or whatever the value of `x` is at the time of function creation) without using another global variable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with global variables alone. When a function is defined, none of the variables in the function body are actually evaluated till the function is called. What you want seems to be a closure to hold the value at the time of creation. Instead write a function that returns a function

```
x <- 5
getfun <- function() {z<-x; function() return(z)}
f <- getfun()
x<- 10
g <- getfun()
f()
# [1] 5
g()
# [1] 10
```

Or even better, don't implicitly use global variables. Create a function that takes a certain set of parameters and returns a new function

```
returnVal <- function(x) {force(x); function() return(x)}
f<-returnVal(5)
g<-returnVal(10)
f()
# [1] 5
g()
# [1] 10
```

Comment: With a one liner: `f <- (function() {z<-x; function() return(z)})()`.

Comment: “Variables are not evaluated unless their value is actually requested” — This is wrong. It’s only true for promises (including function arguments).

Comment: Ah, indeed. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

Still another option using `body`:

```
f<-`body<-`(function() {},value=x)
```

Example:

```
x<-10
f<-`body<-`(function() {},value=x)
f()
#[1] 10
x<-100
f()
#[1] 10
```

Digging the source code of `body`, here is an even cleaner solution equivalent to the above using `as.function`:

```
f<-as.function(list(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This saves the value of x the first time f is called and then uses that value of x even if x has been changed the next time f is called. Create f in a local environment and have f place x in that environment.  If x was not previously there it will now be.  If it was previously there then it will be the x retrieved and placed back.  The result is that the first x encountered will always be used.

```
f <- local(function() {
      p <- parent.env(environment())
      p$x <- x
      x
})


x <- 5
f()
## [1] 5
x <- 10
f()
## [1] 5
```

**2)** In comments @Konrad and @Frank have suggested the following variation in which we remove the assignment from f and put it in the local.

There is one difference from the viewpoint of the user of the function. This instantiates the value of x at the time the function is defined whereas (1) instantiates x the first time that the function is called and that might be an advantage if you want to separate the definition and the instantiation.

```
x <- 5
f <- local({ x <- x; function() x })
f()
## [1] 5
x <- 10
f()
## [1] 5
```

**3)** We can also consider completely separating the function from the instantiation.  This would also allow re-initialization at any time by calling e$init() again.

```
e <- local({
        init <- function() {
           p <- parent.env(environment())
           p$x <- x
        }
        run = function() x
        environment()
   })

x <- 5
e$init()
e$run()
## [1] 5

x <- 10
e$run()
## [1] 5
```

**4)** (3) could be implemented using a variety of object oriented frameworks such as Reference Classes, proto or R6.  In proto it would be like this:

```
library(proto)

p <- proto(init = function(.) .$x <- x, run = function(.) x)

x <- 5
p$init()
p$run()
## [1] 5

x <- 10
p$run()
## [1] 5
```

Comment: No need for `parent.env` — `x <- x` works perfectly fine (although it looks admittedly odd).

Comment: We need to inject x into the parent environment, not just retrieve it.  x <- x won't do that.

Comment: I've done `f <- local({x = 5; function() x})` before, which seems to work.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, exactly like shown in the answer now.